How to set up a rejection folder In ABBYY Flexicapture 12
We are using ABBYY FLEXICAPTURE 12 for Invoice. We have a scenario, only Non voice category files- ex: Credit notes, Credit Memo, Statement, Receipt kind of files should go to Rejected folder automatically. Currently Verification user change the status manually.
Also need to send those files in email attachment as a next step if feasible.
Please guide.

@Vladimir.Dimitrijevic any suggestions please.
